# jquery show() not working

Tags: php, jquery

im making a todo list app in php and im using unordered lists to print them out.What I want is to display the titles of todo lists to be displayed first and their contents hidden initially but displayed later via the click event in jQuery.This is what i have tried so far...

```
<?php 
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$todo = $_POST['todo'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO todo (todo,name) 
 VALUES('$todo','$name')")  
 or die (mysql_error());
 $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM todo");
$todofeed .= ' <ul id = "nav">';         
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
$name1 = $row["name"];
$todofeed.='<li class="title"><a href="#">' . $name1 . '</a></li>';

$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT id, todo FROM todo WHERE name='$name1' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
{$todo1 = $row["todo"];

    $todofeed.='<ul>
    <li id="items">' . $todo1 . '</li>
</ul>';}}
    $todofeed .= '</ul>';     
     print "$todofeed";

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

  li#items
    {
   display:none;
  }
     </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


$('ul#nav li#title').click(function() {
 $('li#items').css('display' , 'visible');
});
});
       </script>
```

any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul#nav li.title').click(function() {
```

because of your

`$todofeed.='<li class="title"><a href="#">' . $name1 . '</a></li>';`

Comment: Yuli Chika answered first by 1 second :)

Comment: @Scuzzy, woo~~ never notice that :)

Comment: @Scuzzy and yuli did that and its still not working...is there any other problem?i even removed the <a> tag...

Comment: @higfox, can you provid us the printed html code to http://jsfiddle.net/?  Or try `$('li#items').css('display' , 'block'); `

Comment: @yulichika the code i have written in this question is the entire thing and your 2nd option is not working...

Comment: @higfox, ok, let us simulate your situation, http://jsfiddle.net/JtVwW/, am I right?

Comment: @higfox, so it should work. what is your problem? I think you could parst your html resourse code to jsfiddle.net, so i could help you as i could.

Comment: @yulichika btw this is an ajax page..i.e the displaying div is in another page

Comment: @higfox, if it is an ajax page, you could try `$('ul#nav li.title').live('click',function() {`, see http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

Your list element has a class name and not a ID, try

```
$('ul#nav li.title')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use "a" instead "li.title", to prevent default link click behaviour

```
$('#nav').on('click', 'li.title a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#nav .items').hide(); 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/JaPbV/1/